# Rails Can Can Ability Class For Multiple Devise Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan, activeadmin

I was wondering how I can define an ability class and serve that ability class depending on the user that has logged in.

I am using Active Admin, Can Can and Devise and I have successfully created a User and an AdminUser models.

I have this in my ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    if (user)
      can :manage, Item
    end
  end
end
```

Now I have used this wiki entry to determine that we can indeed define a custom ability file and use that instead of the ability.rb:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/changing-defaults

But what I wanted to do is, be able to use ability.rb if a "non-admin user" is signed in and a custom abilty if a user admin is signed in.

**Side Question**: Could it be done such that I don't need a custom one and I could set permissions in one ability.rb file?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't notice that you had used a separate class for User and AdminUser. You should be able to change the class used by Active Admin, but not being a user of that system, I'm not sure exactly where that is. Probably should check your initializers though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've never really used ActiveAdmin, so I'm not entirely sure if I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem like that framework relies on CanCan. That's why I'm assuming you're defining a `current_ability` method like explained in the wiki and it's instantiated with `Ability.new(current_user)`.

If that's the case, and your `current_user` can be either a `User` or an `AdminUser`, then there's no problem in checking for that in the `Ability` class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    if user.kind_of? AdminUser
      can :manage, Item
    elsif user.kind_of? User
      can :read, Item
    end
  end
end
```

You can simply take a look at the user's type and change the rules accordingly. You can also use `is_a?` instead of `kind_of?` for stricter checking, but it's probably not required and might cause issues if you decide to do inheritance later on.

Another way you could check is by defining an `admin?` method in both models. This might be a better way to do it, since explicit type checking is not very popular in ruby -- it often limits your choices. It might look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def admin?
    false
  end
end

class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  def admin?
    true
  end
end

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    if user.admin?
      can :manage, Item
    else
      can :read, Item
    end
  end
end
```